# Nested for loop with three variables - order of execution clarity - Appending all variable combinations

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I am working with a file which includes an automated calculation for given inputs. Using [Sub:Other_Sub_Calc].

The aim of this code is to get all combinations of the 3 different variables (listed in 'sheet4' columns a:c) along with the corresponding result [Cell: b61]copied on to a separate sheet(rather than running each combination individually).

The code seems to work with just the two variables in places but I've messed up somewhere adding the third.

I'm sorry for my very bad vba knowledge, I'd imagine someone with better knowledge may be able to spot my mistake in this simple code relatively quickly.

Thank you in advance if anyone can help.

```
Sub Expected_results()


Dim age, town, studylength As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer

'Variables
Set age = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("a2:a5")
Set town = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("b2:b6")
Set studylength = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("c2:c6")



For Each Year In age
    Sheets("Summary").Range("B28").Value = volume

        For Each Location In town
            Sheets("Summary").Range("B34").Value = Ratio
           
           For Each duration In studylength
            Sheets("Summary").Range("B29").Value = Ratio
            
            
            Other_Sub_Calc 'Example Sub to be ran for each combination of variables
            
'copy and append each generated result
 Worksheets("Summary").Range("b61").Copy 
 Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("d2" & lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial
                  
        Next age
        
    Next Location
        
Next duration


End Sub
```

Comment: Your next statements are in the wrong order.  Should be Next duration, next location, next age.

Comment: As posted that code would not run for the reason above. Why use Ratio twice?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I thought I had sorry as I had noticed errors in my previous question, done now